# Battery not recognized on my laptop (and it recognizes my laptop as a desktop)

Tags: 10.10, 11.04, laptop, battery, acpi

I have installed Ubuntu (both 10.10 and 11.04 pre-release) on my laptop but my battery is not recognized and it is detected as a desktop system rather than a laptop.

- I have tried to get the output of `cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/state` but the directory doesn't exist.
- I have tried another guide to paste the battery info into this directory but it doesn't allow me to do that and says that the directory doesn't exist, even though I'm trying to make it.
- I tried it in root Nautilus and even on an install of Lubuntu (with a root file manager) but it still failed to budge. I really don't know what to do as I have tried all the guides on the internet that I could find.

Is there any way to change the configuration file(s) that detect the internal hardware of the computer. The /proc directory is a temporary RAM directory afaik. Is there a directory where that data is stored permanently and where the RAM reads if you know what I mean? 
Thanks in advance.

AZorin

This issue has been reported as [bug #764513](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/764513).

Comment: It should be BAT0, not BAT1.

Comment: Unfortunately BAT0 didn't work either. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you file a bug report about this. I would use the `ubuntu-bug linux` command in a terminal and see what the bug triagers are able to figure out for you.

Comment: I submitted it as a bug report. Is there any way to change the configuration file(s) that detect the internal hardware of the computer. The /proc directory is a temporary RAM directory afaik. Is there a directory where that data is stored permanently and where the RAM reads if you know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a lenovo y460 that I fixed by unplugging the computer, removing the battery, and pressing the power button for about 10 seconds to reset the hardware (might be different for your computer).

If you run windows ever, Windows can change your battery settings (somehow) and make it unreadable by some linux distros.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately that didn't work for me.